# Tkinter local variable 'calcButton' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style


class Example(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

    self.parent = parent

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Multiplication")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("clam")

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    E1 = Entry(bd =5)
    E1.place(x=0, y=0)
    E2 = Entry(bd=5)
    E2.place(x=125, y=0)
    E3 = Entry(bd=5)
    E3.place(x=62.5, y=25)
    calcButton = Button(self, text="Button", command=calcButton.calculate)
    calcButton.place(x=50, y=50)
def calculate(calcButton):
    a = E1.get()
    b = E2.get()
    c = E3.get()


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I'm getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python27\tkinter", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Python27\tkinter", line 43, in main
    app = Example(root)
  File "E:\Python27\tkinter", line 15, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "E:\Python27\tkinter", line 31, in initUI
    calcButton = Button(self, text="Button", command=calcButton.calculate)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'calcButton' referenced before assignment`

I apologize for incorrect indentation, this code pasting is difficult.
I've looked at the duplicate questions and have tried what they said, but nothing worked.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `command=self.calculate` instead of `command=calcButton.calculate`.

Comment: put that as an answer

Comment: I'm too lazy, accept Ganesh Kamath's answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this line you are using:

```
calcButton = Button(self, text="Button", command=calcButton.calculate)
```

where `calcButton.calculate` is being called to assign it to `calcButton` but it has not been declared yet.

This should probably be:

```
calcButton = Button(self, text="Button", self.calculate)
```